# Pandas df.pivot_table - aggfunc = sum not producing desired output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Say I have a data frame, `sega_df`:

```
MONTH            Character     Rings    Chili Dogs  Emeralds  
0    Jun 2017    Sonic          25.0          10.0       6.0
5    Jun 2017    Sonic          19.0          15.0       0.0
8    Jun 2017    Shadow         4.0           1.0        0.0
9    Jun 2017    Shadow         23.0          1.0        0.0
12   Jun 2017    Knuckles       9.0           3.0        1.0 
13   Jun 2017    Tails          10.0          6.0        0.0
22   Jul 2017    Sonic          5.0           20.0       0.0
23   Jul 2017    Shadow         3.0           3.0        7.0
24   Jul 2017    Knuckles       9.0           4.0        0.0
27   Jul 2017    Knuckles       11.0          2.0        0.0    
28   Jul 2017    Tails          12.0          3.0        0.0  
29   Jul 2017    Tails          12.0          5.0        0.0
```

My `pivot_table` command gives me a table output of each character by row against each month, but the values are a series of random `Nan` or `0`. The `0`s are because there is more data with 0s in later months and I only posted the first few rows. **The data types of the values in the three columns (`Rings`,`Chili Dogs`, and `Emeralds`) are `numpy.float64`, so I'm also curious if that affects it, or if it's how I define `aggfunc`.**

My `values` argument and `pivot_table` commmand is as follows:

```
values = list(sega_df.columns.values)
test = pd.pivot_table(data = sega_df, values = values, index = 'Character', columns = 'MONTH', aggfunc='sum')
```

Here is my desired `pivot_table` output, -- with the sum of the three columns per character per month *(eg. Sonic for month of June is [25 + 10 + 6 + 19 + 15 + 0] = 75.0):*

```
MONTH            Jun 2017       Jul 2017            
Character            
0    Sonic       75.0           25.0          
1    Shadow      29.0           18.0          
2    Knuckles    13.0           26.0           
3    Tails       16.0           32.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need `groupby` `sum` and `sum` with `axis = 1` , then we `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['Character','MONTH']).sum().sum(1).unstack()
Out[953]: 
MONTH      Jul2017  Jun2017
Character                  
Knuckles      26.0     13.0
Shadow        13.0     29.0
Sonic         25.0     75.0
Tails         32.0     16.0
```

Comment: just a question, @Wen -- does this and the pivot_table() work in a similar matter? Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: @ia_wing yes, it should work as the same , just need to sum with level of the correct index .